# Query takes long time on 'statistics' state

Tags: mysql

One of my query takes long time(more than 300 seconds) for executing simple query. and fails in statistics state.

It happens while concurrent execution of same query.

"`select 1 from <table_name> where id = <value> for update`"

Even, i have 'optimizer_search_depth' config as 0 and buffer size has 14GB.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT .... FOR UPDATE` sets a read lock on the rows it returns until the transaction is done, therefor when you call the same query multiple times at the same time, the other ones have to wait for the locks to get released

I guess you are using innodb as engine for your table?

Please see [innodb-locking-reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) for further information on locking with "FOR UPDATE"